# Cookies for different browser

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I am using asp.net with c#.

My issue is this that I am setting cookies to check that the same user is returning or not but user are returing from the same machine with different browser. Is their any alternate I would know that same machine user had visited my site.

Comment: Also please tel me if I save the details in database, like user computer name or something. but I suspect that even in this case there can be mutiple computer with same name.

Comment: Can you keep the key functionality post-login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not unless you checked their IP, but then again that's probably worse since multiple computers are usually hiding behind 1 IP.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is - NO !!!

If there was a way to track the same user no matter what s/he is using, than browser vendors and protocol specification would be doing an awful job in protecting our privacy :))